# Positioning hyperlink over an image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with positioning a link over an image. I am using the opacity and a hover state for this link and I managed to get it to work, but the outcome is not what I expected. The hover doesn't work the way I want. I believe there are better ways of doing this, hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks!

Here is HTML code:

```
<ul id="content-images">
<li><img class="show2" src="img/some_img.png" width="176" height="168"></li>
<li><img class="show2" src="img/some_img2.png" width="176" height="168"></li>
<li><img class="show2" src="img/some_img3.png" width="176" height="168"></li>
</ul>
<span class="show"><a href="#">Link1</a></span>
<span class="show"><a href="#">Link2</a></span>
```

And CSS code:

```
.show {
    opacity:0.8;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
  }
 .show:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
  }
 .show2 {
    left: 1px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    top: -39px;
  }
 .show2:hover {
    opacity:1.0
  }
```

Comment: Is using image maps still viable?

Comment: What do you want exactly? And what is not  the way tou want? I dont get it

Comment: u have to add that img as background for link

Comment: @DanielX2010 I would like to make just one hover state for both image and link, at the moment when I hover it over, it looks like there are two separate hover states for link and for image i.e. when the mouse is over a link the image opacity goes back to 0.8, and when the mouse is over an image the link opacity goes back to 0.8..thanks!

Comment: But then why don't you put the `<img>` elements inside the `<a>` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the link and the image to "behave as one", you should use javascript.
Below, i wrote an example of how it would work for a link and an image in a very simplistic way. Live demo is available at JSFiddle: <kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxwcJ/)**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="content-images">
<li><img id="image1" class="show2" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="176" height="168"></li>
</ul>
<span id="link1" class="show"><a href="#">Link1</a></span>
```

**JS (JQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hover image
    $('#image1').hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",0.8);
        $("#link1").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
    });
    //reestablish previous display when mouse out
    $('#image1').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
        $("#link1").fadeTo("slow",1);
    });
    //hover link
    $('#link1').hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",0.8);
        $("#image1").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
    });
    //reestablish previous display when mouse out
    $('#link1').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
        $("#image1").fadeTo("slow",1);
    });
});
```

OBS: If you don't want any transition animation, just get rid of the `"slow"` argument inside `fadeTo` or change it to `"fast"` if you want it to be faster